# List index out of range error - Help requested

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the fist item in each line within the bgp_summary string and create a new list of these. I am using below code for this purpose, but getting "list index out of range" error. I believe that the list index I am referring is not out of range but not sure why this error is happening.
Would appreciate if some one can help.

```
bgp_summary = """

10.0.13.213     65510    658     86       0       0  2d 3:43:06 Establ
172.46.42.134   65513    819     7        0      11  2d 3:50:49 Establ
172.57.13.1     65501    15427   52       0       0  0d 2:26:01 Establ
172.57.13.249   65513    13449   2517     0       0  2d 3:50:21 Establ
172.57.13.250   65513    134     2515     0       0  4d 3:50:21 Establ
172.57.13.252   65513    46      142      0       0     3:50:32 Establ

"""

bgp_peers_list_raw = []
bgp_peers_list_refined = []
bgp_peers_list_raw = bgp_summary.splitlines()

n=0
for n in range (len(bgp_peers_list_raw)):
    list_raw1 = []
    list_raw1 = bgp_peers_list_raw[n].split()
    bgp_peers_list_refined.append(list_raw1[0])


bgp_peers_list_refined.append(list_raw1[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your lines are empty.  If you discard those like:

#### Code:

```
bgp_peers_list_raw = [l.strip() for l in bgp_summary.splitlines() 
                      if l.strip()]
```

It will work fine.

#### Test Code:

```
bgp_summary = """

10.0.13.213     65510    658     86       0       0  2d 3:43:06 Establ
172.46.42.134   65513    819     7        0      11  2d 3:50:49 Establ
172.57.13.1     65501    15427   52       0       0  0d 2:26:01 Establ
172.57.13.249   65513    13449   2517     0       0  2d 3:50:21 Establ
172.57.13.250   65513    134     2515     0       0  4d 3:50:21 Establ
172.57.13.252   65513    46      142      0       0     3:50:32 Establ

"""

bgp_peers_list_raw = []
bgp_peers_list_refined = []
bgp_peers_list_raw = [l.strip() for l in bgp_summary.splitlines()
                      if l.strip()]

n = 0
for n in range(len(bgp_peers_list_raw)):
    list_raw1 = []
    list_raw1 = bgp_peers_list_raw[n].split()
    bgp_peers_list_refined.append(list_raw1[0])

bgp_peers_list_refined.append(list_raw1[0])
print(bgp_peers_list_refined)
```

#### Results:

```
['10.0.13.213', '172.46.42.134', '172.57.13.1', '172.57.13.249',
 '172.57.13.250', '172.57.13.252', '172.57.13.252']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `bgp_summary` has some empty lines.

The easiest and most straight forward solution is to convert your `bgp_summary` from:

```
bgp_summary = """

10.0.13.213     65510    658     86       0       0  2d 3:43:06 Establ
172.46.42.134   65513    819     7        0      11  2d 3:50:49 Establ
172.57.13.1     65501    15427   52       0       0  0d 2:26:01 Establ
172.57.13.249   65513    13449   2517     0       0  2d 3:50:21 Establ
172.57.13.250   65513    134     2515     0       0  4d 3:50:21 Establ
172.57.13.252   65513    46      142      0       0     3:50:32 Establ

"""
```

to:

```
bgp_summary = """10.0.13.213     65510    658     86       0       0  2d 3:43:06 Establ
172.46.42.134   65513    819     7        0      11  2d 3:50:49 Establ
172.57.13.1     65501    15427   52       0       0  0d 2:26:01 Establ
172.57.13.249   65513    13449   2517     0       0  2d 3:50:21 Establ
172.57.13.250   65513    134     2515     0       0  4d 3:50:21 Establ
172.57.13.252   65513    46      142      0       0     3:50:32 Establ"""
```

which while not as nice looking fixes your problem.

A more complicated solution that leaves your `bgp_summary` untouched would be a small modification to your for loop.

Instead of checking every line like this:

```
range(len(bgp_peers_list_raw))
```

You could exclude the empty ones at the start and at the end like this:

```
#2 empty lines at the start
#1 empty line at the end
range(2, len(bgp_peers_list_raw)-1)
```